# How to get a specific string from file?

Tags: python, arrays, string, file

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{"objects":[{"featureId":"ckm39acfw00043b6a4i8vv8zf","schemaId":"ckm399dnn07ax0y8hdncv51yy","title":"Buildings","value":"buildings","color":"#1CE6FF","bbox":{
top":110,"left":799,"height":42,"width":53},"instanceURI":<"https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckm39acfw00043b6a4i8vv8zf?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja20yN3F1aDVwNzh2MDc4OXh3YmE3eWo5Iiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja20yN3F0cm1wNzhvMDc4OXBlaHJiZG4wIiwiaWF0IjoxNjE1MzcyNjUxLCJleHAiOjE2MTc5NjQ2NTF9.ALYeG0mpNvnOpAuj6O3h0OFcrREOtOvJqqVqqt8xcqw"
},{"featureId":"ckm39agzr00073b6alzzwpm77","schemaId":"ckm399dnn07ax0y8hdncv51yy","title":"Buildings","value":"buildings","color":"#1CE6FF","bbox":

{"top":151,"left":875,"height":45,"width":120},"instanceURI":"https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckm39agzr00073b6alzzwpm77?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja20yN3F1aDVwNzh2MDc4OXh3YmE3eWo5Iiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja20yN3F0cm1wNzhvMDc4OXBlaHJiZG4wIiwiaWF0IjoxNjE1MzcyNjUxLCJleHAiOjE2MTc5NjQ2NTF9.ALYeG0mpNvnOpAuj6O3h0OFcrREOtOvJqqVqqt8xcqw"},{"featureId":"ckm39an0e000a3b6ae7vc0bo8","schemaId":"ckm399dnn07ax0y8hdncv51yy","title":"Buildings","value":"buildings","color":"#1CE6FF","bbox":{"top":635,"left":952,"height":93,"width":84},"instanceURI":"https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckm39an0e000a3b6ae7vc0bo8?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja20yN3F1aDVwNzh2MDc4OXh3YmE3eWo5Iiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja20yN3F0cm1wNzhvMDc4OXBlaHJiZG4wIiwiaWF0IjoxNjE1MzcyNjUxLCJleHAiOjE2MTc5NjQ2NTF9.ALYeG0mpNvnOpAuj6O3h0OFcrREOtOvJqqVqqt8xcqw"},{"featureId":"ckm39bbki000g3b6au6s5s3se","schemaId":"ckm399dnn07ax0y8hdncv51yy","title":"Buildings","value":"buildings","color":"#1CE6FF","bbox":{"top":646,"left":764,"height":74,"width":93},"instanceURI":"https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckm39bbki000g3b6au6s5s3se?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja20yN3F1aDVwNzh2MDc4OXh3YmE3eWo5Iiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja20yN3F0cm1wNzhvMDc4OXBlaHJiZG4wIiwiaWF0IjoxNjE1MzcyNjUxLCJleHAiOjE2MTc5NjQ2NTF9.ALYeG0mpNvnOpAuj6O3h0OFcrREOtOvJqqVqqt8xcqw"
},{"featureId":"ckm39cgdi000p3b6aru669fzh","schemaId":"ckm399dnn07ax0y8hdncv51yy","title":"Buildings","value":"buildings","color":"#1CE6FF","bbox":

{"top":375,"left":916,"height":52,"width":80},"instanceURI":"https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckm39cgdi000p3b6aru669fzh?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja20yN3F1aDVwNzh2MDc4OXh3YmE3eWo5Iiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja20yN3F0cm1wNzhvMDc4OXBlaHJiZG4wIiwiaWF0IjoxNjE1MzcyNjUxLCJleHAiOjE2MTc5NjQ2NTF9.ALYeG0mpNvnOpAuj6O3h0OFcrREOtOvJqqVqqt8xcqw"
},{"featureId":"ckm39ckyi000s3b6armui3tn3","schemaId":"ckm399dnn07ax0y8hdncv51yy","title":"Buildings","value":"buildings","color":"#1CE6FF","bbox":{"top":420,"left":914,"height":72,"width":86},"instanceURI":"https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckm39ckyi000s3b6armui3tn3?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja20yN3F1aDVwNzh2MDc4OXh3YmE3eWo5Iiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja20yN3F0cm1wNzhvMDc4OXBlaHJiZG4wIiwiaWF0IjoxNjE1MzcyNjUxLCJleHAiOjE2MTc5NjQ2NTF9.ALYeG0mpNvnOpAuj6O3h0OFcrREOtOvJqqVqqt8xcqw"
},{"featureId":"ckm39cp6a000v3b6a6cjj16xp","schemaId":"ckm399dnn07ax0y8hdncv51yy","title":"Buildings","value":"buildings","color":"#1CE6FF","bbox":{"top":478,"left":867,"height":66,"width":137},"instanceURI":"https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckm39cp6a000v3b6a6cjj16xp?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja20yN3F1aDVwNzh2MDc4OXh3YmE3eWo5Iiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja20yN3F0cm1wNzhvMDc4OXBlaHJiZG4wIiwiaWF0IjoxNjE1MzcyNjUxLCJleHAiOjE2MTc5NjQ2NTF9.ALYeG0mpNvnOpAuj6O3h0OFcrREOtOvJqqVqqt8xcqw"},{"featureId":"ckm39cyom000y3b6aqp2x5i0s","schemaId":"ckm399dnn07ax0y8hdncv51yy","title":"Buildings","value":"buildings","color":"#1CE6FF","bbox":{"top":703,"left":806,"height":85,"width":95},"instanceURI":"https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckm39cyom000y3b6aqp2x5i0s?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja20yN3F1aDVwNzh2MDc4OXh3YmE3eWo5Iiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja20yN3F0cm1wNzhvMDc4OXBlaHJiZG4wIiwiaWF0IjoxNjE1MzcyNjUxLCJleHAiOjE2MTc5NjQ2NTF9.ALYeG0mpNvnOpAuj6O3h0OFcrREOtOvJqqVqqt8xcqw"},{"featureId":"ckm39dz3t00143b6a2brbj4qi","schemaId":"ckm399dnn07ax0y8hdncv51yy","title":"Buildings","value":"buildings","color":"#1CE6FF","bbox":{"top":41,"left":823,"height":50,"width":80},"instanceURI":"https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckm39dz3t00143b6a2brbj4qi?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja20yN3F1aDVwNzh2MDc4OXh3YmE3eWo5Iiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja20yN3F0cm1wNzhvMDc4OXBlaHJiZG4wIiwiaWF0IjoxNjE1MzcyNjUxLCJleHAiOjE2MTc5NjQ2NTF9.ALYeG0mpNvnOpAuj6O3h0OFcrREOtOvJqqVqqt8xcqw"},{"featureId":"ckm39eco400173b6a35p84q7y","schemaId":"ckm399dnn07ax0y8hdncv51yy","title":"Buildings","value":"buildings","color":"#1CE6FF","bbox":{"top":31,"left":892,"height":62,"width":95},"instanceURI":"https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckm39eco400173b6a35p84q7y?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja20yN3F1aDVwNzh2MDc4OXh3YmE3eWo5Iiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja20yN3F0cm1wNzhvMDc4OXBlaHJiZG4wIiwiaWF0IjoxNjE1MzcyNjUxLCJleHAiOjE2MTc5NjQ2NTF9.ALYeG0mpNvnOpAuj6O3h0OFcrREOtOvJqqVqqt8xcqw"}],"classifications":[]}
```

and I want to save in array all occurrences of top, left, right, height and width. How can I do that?

Comment: The typical format here is to post code you've tried so some folks can help answer. Not just solve your problem for you.

Comment: Also, the JSON you provided is invalid, this may be due to a copy-paste error?

Comment: ok, is my very first question. Sorry for that

Comment: It would also be useful if you showed what the resulting array _should_ look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the JSON file does not look valid. For my answer I'll assume a valid file like so:

```
#example.json
{
  "top":151,
  "left":875,
  "height":45,
  "width":120
}
```

Next you can use python's builtin library 'json' to load the json and extract information:

```
import json

with open('test.json', 'r') as fh:
    d = json.load(fh)
print(d.get('top'))
```

Notice that first you load the json file's content into a dictionary and then you can access it's contents in the same way you would a dictionary using `d.get('top')` or `d['top']`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now i have this error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" at this line -> print(d.get('top'))

Comment: I believe this is caused by your json file which contains invalid dict and list levels. Make sure it looks something like this:
{
  "objects": ["obj1","obj2"],
  "top":151,
  "left":875,
  "height":45,
  "width":120
}

Comment: yes, the structure of my json is different. Finally i try :

 print(data[0]["Label"]["objects"][0]["bbox"]["top"])

And it's work!